# Let people grant my app Outlook APIs access to all users in a tenant

Tags: outlook, office365

How can I let people grant my code that uses the Outlook APIs access to all users in a tenant without adding the tenant to the application manually? I know I can give the application permissions from within the Azure management portal of the tenant, but what if I do not have access myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily for you there is some new functionality that allows you to do exactly this, in the new 'app model v2' (the new login model for applications on Azure AD). You can find some generic info on the App model v2 [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview/). What you're looking for specifically in the app model v2 is the admin consent, you can find a blogpost on this [here](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/implementing-admin-consent-multitenant-office-365-applications-implicit-oauth-flow/).